# NSTableView don't display data

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have data in `NSMutableArray` and I want to display it in `NSTableView`, but only the number of cols has changed.
This use of `NSTableView` is based on tutorial [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5teN5pMf-rs).
FinalImageBrowser is `IBOutlet` to `NSTableView`.

```
@implementation AppController

NSMutableArray *listData;


- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [FinalImageBrowser setDataSource:self];
}

- (IBAction)StartReconstruction:(id)sender 
{
    NSMutableArray *ArrayOfFinals = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; //Array of list with final images
    NSString *FinalPicture;
    NSString *PicNum;
    int FromLine = [TextFieldFrom intValue]; //read number of start line 
    int ToLine = [TextFieldTo intValue];     //read number of finish line
    int RecLine;

    for (RecLine = FromLine; RecLine < ToLine; RecLine++)  //reconstruct from line to line
    {
        Start(RecLine);    //start reconstruction
                //Create path of final image
        FinalPicture = @"FIN/final";
        PicNum = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d", RecLine];
        FinalPicture = [FinalPicture stringByAppendingString:PicNum];
        FinalPicture = [FinalPicture stringByAppendingString:@".bmp"];
        [ArrayOfFinals addObject:FinalPicture]; // add path to array

    }


    listData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [listData autorelease]; 

    [listData addObjectsFromArray:ArrayOfFinals];

    [FinalImageBrowser reloadData]; 

    NSBeep(); //make some noise

    NSImage *fin = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:FinalPicture];
    [FinalImage setImage:fin];

}


- (int)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)tv {
    return [listData count];
}

- (id)tableView:(NSTableView *)tv objectValueFromTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(int)row {
    return (NSString *)[listData objectAtIndex:row];
}

@end
```

When the StartReconstruction end the number of cols have changed right, but they're empty. When I debug app, items in listData is rigth.

Comment: Have you heard of "debugging"? It's when you insert log statements in different places in your program and see if they're reached and whether correct data returned. Try this in your code.

Comment: I've tried debugg this app for 5 hours...but I didn't found what can be wrong :(

Comment: Just a note on coding style… you should make sure that instances of objects do not start with a capital letter. Only class names themselves should be capitalised. Method names should never start with a capital letter. Have a read of the [Objective-C coding guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/CodingGuidelines.html)

Comment: @Tomas What's the result, then? Is every method invoked? Does `numberOfRowsInTableView` return correct value? And so on.

Comment: @Tomas Svoboda: What do you mean by “only the number of cols has changed”? The code you show doesn't add or remove any columns. What were you expecting to happen? What happened instead? Please be specific and thorough. Also, unless you're building with garbage collection enabled, you're leaking both `ArrayOfFinals` and `fin`.

Comment: thanks for answers. Sorry I make mistake...The number of rows in NSTableView has changed (like empty items), but nothing else. If I make breakpoint at  return (NSString *)[listData objectAtIndex:row]; program didn't stopped at it. but in tutorial (see youtube) it is fine :(

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you forgot to connect the `FinalImageBrowser` outlet to the table view. That would mean your `setDataSource:` message is to `nil`, which would leave the table view without a data source.

You don't need to send that message anyway—you can set the data source in the nib. Remove your `awakeFromNib` implementation and connect the table view's `dataSource` outlet to your data source object in IB, as well as the `FinalImageBrowser` outlet to the table view (also in IB).